# Material UI tooltip notice error for first render

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I am using Material tooltip in react. I have created a custom component wrapper for tooltip MaterialTooltip like below:

```
import { Tooltip } from '@mui/material';

const MaterialTooltip = props => {
  return (
    <Tooltip
      PopperProps={{ sx: { fontSize: '16px' } }}
      arrow={props.disableArrow || !props.title ? false : true}
      placement={props.placement ? props.placement : 'top'}
      title={props.title ? props.title : ''}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default MaterialTooltip;
```

And calling it like this:

```
{
  myArray.map((row, index) => {
    return (
      <MaterialTooltip key={index} title={row.condition ? tooltipText : ''}>
        <div className={someDynamicClass}>{row.text}</div>
      </MaterialTooltip>
    );
  });
}
```

When I first hover over the text, where tooltip exists, it show an error in console only for the first time:
[image]
For the subsequent hover or any other sentence hover after that, doesnt have any error.
Can anyone suggest the reason and possible solution for this error? It is rendering the tooltip properly, but console is giving this error only once.

Update: The issue occurring only on development build not on production build.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. Did you able to find any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably comes from elsewhere, it works well : [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-lena-1glbm5?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Thanks, I checked, this issue is not in production build, only exists in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

There were no error with your code.
Are myArray's data static? I think it's data changes and cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it loads the data dynamically, but after the data is loaded, it is static, no changes happen dynamically in array. So when I am first hovering over the tooltip, before that data was loaded completely.